# Folder name change through programmatically

Tags: c#, structure, filenames, directory

I have folders like          C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\Test\DUT3_Mode1A\DUT3_Mode1B\DUT3_Mode2.

I will browse folder upto Test. I need to change if name contains Mode1A then I just rename as M1A like different condition with names. For example I have path like DUT3_Mode1A\DUT3_Mode1B\DUT3_Mode2 I need to rename DUT3_M1A\DUT3_M1B\DUT3_M2

see below example like what I need to change folder structure.

```
    M1A = Mode1A
    M1B = Mode1B
    M2 = Mode2
    M3 = Mode3
    M6 = Mode6
    Read = Read DTCs
    Clear = Clear DTCs
    EPB = EPB_APPL-REL
    PWRD = POWER_DOWN    


using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace FolderStructure
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        string strpath = string.Empty;
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            fbd.Description = "Custom Description";

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string sSelectedPath = fbd.SelectedPath;
                textBox1.Text = sSelectedPath;
                strpath = sSelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ChangeFileName(strpath);
        }
        public void ChangeFileName(string folderPath)
        {
            string strtemp = string.Empty;            
            ////string[] folders = folderPath.Split(System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories););
            string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(folderPath, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
            foreach (string path in folders)
            {
                //code needed              

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into the methods provided by the `System.IO.Path`, which can help you with disassembling and composing path strings. Also look into regular expressions (`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`), which most certainly can help you in defining patterns and rules for string substitutions/renamings.

Comment: You need to present a problem with existing code, not ask the readers to write code for you. `//Need Code` needs to be substituted with code you have written to attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @elgonzo in this case a string replace function on each folder name might be easier than digging into regular expressions as Harry just wants to replace `Mode` with `M`. Although it is always good to learn about regular expressions.

Comment: @NOhs, yes, if Harry only want to replace a certain number of specific sub-strings/words, then string.Replace is indeed much simpler. :-)

Comment: Only you know exactly the directory structure and thus can decide the best strategy to use. We don’t know if there are other folders and how strict we have to be on checking file names... If the structure directly under your control or the structure can contains user files...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method will rename all directories and subdirectories in the given path replacing the 'from' string to the 'to' string:

```
public static void Replace(string path, string from, string to)
{
    string prefix = path;
    string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string folder in folders)
    {
        // recursively rename all subfolders first
        Replace(folder, from, to);

        string newFolderName = prefix + folder.Substring(prefix.Length).Replace(from, to);

        if (newFolderName != folder)
            System.IO.Directory.Move(folder, newFolderName);
    }
}
```

Usage

```
    Replace(folderPath, "Mode", "M");
```

---

EDIT: Are you sure you want to change the difficulty level to easy?

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> replacements = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "Mode1A", "M1A" },
    { "Mode1B", "M1B" },
    { "Mode1", "M1" },
    { "Mode2", "M2" },
    { "Mode3", "M3" },
    { "Mode6", "M6" },
    { "Read DTCs", "Read" },
    { "Clear DTCs", "Clear" },
    { "EPB_APPL-REL", "EPB" },
    { "POWER_DOWN", "PWRD" }
};

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangeFolderNames();
}

private void ChangeFolderNames()
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> pair in replacements)
        Replace(strpath, pair.Key, pair.Value);
}

public static void Replace(string path, string from, string to)
{
    string prefix = path;
    string[] folders = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
    foreach (string folder in folders)
    {
        // recursively rename all subfolders first
        Replace(folder, from, to);

        string newFolderName = prefix + folder.Substring(prefix.Length).Replace(from, to);

        if (newFolderName != folder)
            System.IO.Directory.Move(folder, newFolderName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Replay. please find updated code in above and help me what i need to do exactly

Comment: got am exception like Source and destination path must be different.

Comment: i observed  System.IO.Directory.Move(folder, newFolderName);         folder and newFolderName paths are same.

Comment: What was the incoming folder path? Did it match an entry in the dictionary. You should not get an exception as the code checks for a difference before attempting to rename.

Comment: incoming folder path is string prefix = path; this one only

Comment: I mean what is the path? C:\Something\Folder\ etc. Note you should select the path that contains your folder tree, not each individual folder.

Comment: string newFolderName = prefix + folder.Substring(prefix.Length).Replace(from, to);  please check replace not working

Comment: if (newFolderName != folder)
            System.IO.Directory.Move(folder, newFolderName); then working earlier we use ==. finally working thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can modify recursive method below to rename files. The code below writes all filenames to xml format.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace SAveDirectoriesXml
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        const string FOLDER = @"c:\temp";
        static XmlWriter writer = null;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings);
            writer.WriteStartDocument(true);

            DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(FOLDER);
            WriteTree(info);

            writer.WriteEndDocument();
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Return");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        static long WriteTree(DirectoryInfo info)
        {
            long size = 0;
            writer.WriteStartElement("Folder");
            try
            {
                writer.WriteAttributeString("name", info.Name);
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberSubFolders", info.GetDirectories().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("numberFiles", info.GetFiles().Count().ToString());
                writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());


                foreach (DirectoryInfo childInfo in info.GetDirectories())
                {
                    size += WriteTree(childInfo);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception Folder : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
            }

            FileInfo[] fileInfo = null;
            try
            {
                fileInfo = info.GetFiles();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception FileInfo : {0}, Error : {1}", info.FullName, ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                writer.WriteElementString("Error",errorMsg);
            }

            if (fileInfo != null)
            {
                foreach (FileInfo finfo in fileInfo)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartElement("File");
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("name", finfo.Name);
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("size", finfo.Length.ToString());
                        writer.WriteAttributeString("date", info.LastWriteTime.ToString());
                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        size += finfo.Length;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string errorMsg = string.Format("Exception File : {0}, Error : {1}", finfo.FullName, ex.Message);
                        Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
                        writer.WriteElementString("Error", errorMsg);
                    }
                }
            }

            writer.WriteElementString("size", size.ToString());
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            return size;

        }
    }
}
```